# Efficient algorithm for finding directed cycle with smallest average weight

Tags: graph-algorithms

Suppose we have a strongly connected directed graph with non-negative weights on its edges. Is there an efficient algorithm to find the directed cycle with the smallest average weight in the graph? (Here, smallest average weight of a directed cycle is the sum of the weights of all edges in the cycle divided by the number of edges.)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you not post this on [cs.SE]? It does not strike me as a research-level question per se.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Karp has an algorithm that does exactly that. You can read about it in his paper ["A characterization of the minimum cycle mean in a digraph."](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X78900110)

There seem to be other algorithms proposed [here](http://www.math.md/files/csjm/v6-n1/v6-n1-(pp27-34).pdf) which are perhaps easier to read.